# Parsing not return data

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, jsondecoder

hi I want to ask I was trying to parse Json from this Json data

```
{
    "data": {
        "user_attendances": [
            {
                "user": {
                    "id": "028511ec-f384-4fc2-a7d2-8918392c9993",
                    "full_name": "Mariah Carrey"
                },
                "attendance": {
                    "status": "sick"

                }
            }
        ],
        "attended": 7,
        "unattended": 3,
        "present": 7,
        "permission": 1,
        "sick": 1,
        "abstain": 1
    }
}
```

then I make a model I paste from QuickType.io in my swift file

```
struct DataAttendance: Codable {
    let data: DataClass?
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let userAttendances: [UserAttendance]?
    let attended, unattended, present, permission: Int?
    let sick, abstain: Int?

}

// MARK: - UserAttendance
struct UserAttendance: Codable {
    let user        : User?
    let attendance  : AttendanceClass?
}

// MARK: - AttendanceClass
struct AttendanceClass: Codable {
    let status: String?
}

// MARK: - User
struct User: Codable {
    let id, fullName: String?
}
```

since I want save the data in array so I make another model for it

```
struct Attendance {
    var id          : String
    var fullName    : String
    var status      : String
    var attended    : Int
    var unattended  : Int
    var present     : Int
    var permission  : Int
}
```

and since I want to return data from api, I make a request with Alamofire with this method

```
func getUserAttendanceBy(classId: String, date: String, completion: @escaping (Result<Attendance, GAttendanceError>) -> Void) {
        HEADERS["Authorization"] = token
        let params = ["class_id": classId, "attendance_date": date]
        AF.request(API_URL.ATTENDANCE.ATTENDANCE_INDEX, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: HEADERS).responseJSON(completionHandler: { dataResponse in

            if let _ = dataResponse.error {
                completion(.failure(.invalidClassID))
            }

            guard let response = dataResponse.response, response.statusCode == 200 else {
                completion(.failure(.invalidResponse))
                return
            }
            guard let data = dataResponse.data else {
                completion(.failure(.invalidData))
                return
            }

            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

                let json = try decoder.decode(DataAttendance.self, from: data)
                print(json)
            } catch {

            }
        })
    }
```

Then I test it with dummy data but not returning a data even I try to print inside the function

```
UserServices.shared.getUserAttendanceBy(classId: "4bae2594-b3a7-4b9c-ad83-0a1c4be0d790", date: "2020-02-10") { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let attendances):
                print(attendances)

                break
            case .failure(let error):
                break
            }
        }
```

please help me where do I do wrong?

Comment: You don't call `completion` on success and the code to map `DataAttendance` to `Attendance` is missing.

Comment: did you think even though I'm not passing completion while I try to print it should be print out the data right? by the way I try to make the completion, now while I iterating the UserAttendances and try put piece by piece into attendance model. it's still not work @vadian

Comment: If it doesn't print anything then there is an error. However you ignore the `error` in the Decoder `catch` block. `print` it! And print also the error in the `failure` case.

Comment: it still not print error anything @vadian

Comment: It **must** print something. Either `print(json)` on success or one of the errors

Comment: still nothing, I check the endpoint, check the header, check the parameter, even I use dummy classId and dummy date still not printing error or Json. @vadian

Comment: Did you add `print(error)` in both the `JSONDecoder` catch block **and** the `.failure` case? If yes then `getUserAttendanceBy` is not executed.

Comment: I print. in switch case of result, I have the response is invalid classId and invalid response ,  but when I try it in postman it's fine. with the same class id and token and date. sorry @vadian I still don't know what is the problem

Comment: In this case the error is related to the server communication.